# How to get results weighted by references from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a dataset consisting of Notes referencing other Notes.

```
{id:"aaa", note: "lorem ipsum", references: ["ccc"]},
{id:"bbb", note: "lorem ipsum", references: ["aaa","ccc"]},
{id:"ccc", note: "lorem ipsum", references: ["bbb"]},
```

I want elastic search to use the references to weight the results, so in this case if I search for `lorem` I should get id "ccc" back since it has the most references. According to their docs, their graph solution does exactly this, but I also see examples where they are doing similar things.

But no explanation of how this is mapped to the Index. So my question is: how does one set up an ES index that uses references (indices)?

Comment: looks like `id:2` has the most references, assuming the array length represents references, am I missing something?

Comment: No you're right, but this isn't being indexed. Right now it'll do a free text match on "note" which will return them in equal weight. That's my question, how to make them index properly.

Comment: could you add a `integer` field with the references of length at index time?

Comment: @Nate I don’t know what that means? Sounds like that sort of confit is exactly wheat I’m looking for? (The ID in the real code is a uuid string)

Comment: what have you tried? what docs about which graph solution are you referring to?

Comment: @Aprillion ElasticSearch Graph is a visualisation tool for Kibana that shows exactly this sort of relation. I'm not able to use it though, since I'm on AWS.
Currently using a bucket aggregation to find the ID with the most references. But unable to figure out how to sort the original query by this aggregation instead of score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers gave some clues, but then @7379490 provided the answer in another channel:

There is no way of doing this directly in ES. There are two possible solutions:
pre calculate references and pass them into ES by mapping a new value to the document.

Or aggregate and use aggregation to sort the response:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "note": "lorem"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
      "references":{
        "terms" : {
          "field" : "references.keyword",
          "order": { "_count": "desc" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) can be used to give higher score to documents with  more values  for reference field

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "note": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "references": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "note": "lorem"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "_score * doc['references.keyword'].length" --> references length
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
 "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index71",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "iJObRHIBXTOhZcHPaYks",
        "_score" : 0.035661265,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2,
          "note" : "lorem ipsum",
          "references" : [
            1,
            3
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index71",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "h5ObRHIBXTOhZcHPYok2",
        "_score" : 0.017830633,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "note" : "lorem ipsum",
          "references" : [
            3
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index71",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "iZObRHIBXTOhZcHPb4k4",
        "_score" : 0.017830633,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 3,
          "note" : "lorem ipsum",
          "references" : [
            2
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I much appreciate the good answer, but it doesn't solve my problem. In my case the reference is a list of IDs of document. And it is the document ID that has the most references *from other documents* that should come first. The winner might not have a single reference itself.

Comment: @JesperBylund You cannot sort query result by aggregation, aggregation doesn't have any effect on query output and  there are no joins in elasticsearch. You need to resolve this at index time. Create a new field which stores number of documents which reference a document

Comment: How about showing the document that corresponds to that bucket? Filtering for the _term perhaps?

Comment: @JesperBylund top_hits or any other sub aggregation will apply  on documents form which that term is derived. Ex if terms aggregation key is 3 then any other sub aggregation will act on document with id 1 and document with id 2. for which that term(references) is derived, so you cannot use it for global filtering

Comment: @JesperBylund This answer is with respect to elastic search query. For visualization,  I don't have any knowledge. so I am not aware if there is any custom plugin or way to do it

Comment: My question is regarding ES query. The visualisation comment was just because I can see examples of this type for relationships on elastics site, but no examples. Thank you @jaspreet

Answer (score 1):

If your data contain `referencesGiven` and you need to search by `referencesReceived`, I would recommend a 2-way pass:

1. insert all documents with an empty field for `referencesReceived: []` 
   (or `referencesReceivedCount: 0` if that is enough)
2. for each document, for each item in `referencesGiven`, update the document receiving the reference

Comment: Any recommendations on how to do this with ES?

Currently I'm querying for a term, and using ES aggregation I can receive a list of which ID has the most references. But I haven't figured out how to sort the original query result using the aggregation result.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ES indexing that much, but it should be possible to use the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) with any supported programming language that you use for indexing. you didn't include any current code for indexing, so no idea what I could suggest that you modify in your current code :(